# STEP/EXPRESS tools for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, step

Has anyone had any experience with using the [STEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_for_the_Exchange_of_Product_model_data/) and [EXPRESS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPRESS_(data_modeling_language)/) formats in a .Net environment?

I am looking for a tool that will generate a c# class structure based on an EXPRESS schema. I would also like the tool to create a parser/file generator for importing and exporting to STEP-files.

Does anyone know of a tool that does this? Any tools that will bring me closer to my own implementation would also be useful.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204634/convert-express-classes-from-ifc-file-to-vb-net-classes/41416951#41416951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a list of tools you might be interested in on the [PDES website](http://www.pdesinc.com/free_STEP.html). Some of these tools allows for example to generate a XML representation of your EXPRESS schema. It might then be easier to implement your tool from there.

It looks like [Open CASCADE](http://www.opencascade.org/) is open source and developed in a .NET environment.

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a useful tool. I'm downloading it now.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd answer for anyone else who stumbles upon it.

If you need to work with `STEP` and `EXPRESS` and don't want CAD libraries, or if you need an uncommon or custom schema, take a look at (**shameless plug!**) [STEPcode](http://github.com/stepcode/stepcode), which uses the BSD license.

It generates `C++`, not `C#` - but IMO it would be far easier to modify SCL than to start from scratch.

Note that this was formerly known as Step Class Library, the same `SCL` that @roch mentions above. A group of people are improving it, and the NIST version is very dated.

**edit:** new name, new URL

Answer (score 1):

While not .Net, if you are interested in higher-level tools based on open cascade, you should take a look at pythonocc.

Answer (score 0):

[IFC Engine](http://www.ifcbrowser.com/) can also read STEP files via SDAI (Standard Data Access Interface). There is also a C# binding.