# Convert IFC EXPRESS schema entities/classes to VB.NET classes

Tags: vb.net, step, ifc

I'm working on an [ifc](/questions/tagged/ifc) project where I want to convert an `EXPRESS` file's classes into [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) classes. It is really hard to process all the attributes of the `stp` file one by one, so I was wondering if there are alternative ways or tools which could convert the classes.

**EDIT** : I have discovered [javatoolbox](/questions/tagged/javatoolbox) which does exactly what I want, but in [java](/questions/tagged/java). I have also seen `IFC Engine DLL` but have not found any code available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating classes for full EXPRESS schema is relatively complex task. If your language/platform of choice is vb.net I'd recommend to have a look on [xBIM](https://github.com/xBimTeam/). It is open source toolkit which provides all you need to open IFC model and extract/create any data you need. **xBIM** is mostly written in C# so you can just reference it as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xBIM). The latest development code also supports **IFC4**.

Answer (score 1):

Both Jotne EPM www.epmtech.jotne.com and IFC Engine DLL www.ifcengine.com claim they support Visual Basic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen both tools but I have not found any code to convert `EXPRESS` classes to `VB` classes.  Do you know if this code I am looking for exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [oipExpress](https://bitbucket.org/tumcms/oipexpress). oipExpress is a early binding generator written in C++. Just implement our own generator that generates VB.Net classes. Currently, it just generates C++ classes.

A basic generator for VB.Net classes could look like this (the generated binding can be found also [here](https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/earlybindingvbnet_ifc4x1_add1/src)):

```
class GeneratorVBNet : public Generator {
public:
    GeneratorVBNet() {
    }
    virtual ~GeneratorVBNet() {
    }

    void generate(std::ostream &out, OpenInfraPlatform::ExpressBinding::Schema &schema) {
        for (int i = 0; i < schema.getEntityCount(); i++) {
            auto &entity = schema.getEntityByIndex(i);

            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << earlyBindingDestination << "\\" << entity.getName() << ".vb";

            std::ofstream ofs(ss.str(), std::ofstream::out);

            ofs << "Class " << entity.getName() << std::endl;

            ofs << "End Class" << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    std::string earlyBindingDestination = "E:\\dev\\EarlyBindingVBNet_IFC4x1_Add1";
};
```

The generated early binding will look like this: [image: Generated early binding]

The internal meta model of oipExpress looks like this:
[image: oipExpress Meta Model]